# dc.js Adding count to the xAxis label

Tags: dc.js

This is related to the dc.js [boxPlot example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/box-plot.html).  Is there an easy way to add the number of data values to each xAxis label?

exp-1 [10]

I know I can configure the xAxis label by:

```
chart.xAxis().tickFormat(function(k) {return k + ' []';});
```

But I only have access to the key and not the value count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by keeping a map from keys to counts, refreshing it before the chart is rendered or redrawn:

```
var counts = {};
function get_counts() {
    speedArrayGroup.all().forEach(function(kv) {
        counts[kv.key] = kv.value.length;
    });
}
chart.on('preRender', get_counts)
    .on('preRedraw', get_counts);
```

Now that we're sure `counts` is initialized whenever the axis is drawn, we can use it in the `tickFormat`:

```
chart.xAxis().tickFormat(function(k) {return k + ' [' + counts[k] + ']';});
```

Not so interesting with the standard example, but it works:

[image: x axis with counts]

Comment: Perfect.  I know it may not be interesting on this chart, but I will be submitting a new BoxPlot chart for dc.js with new attributes this week.

Comment: I would like to show you an example of the new BoxPlot.  I could put it in jfiddle first before submitting.  How best to pm you?  Can I contribute to https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js?  I have never submitted code to any library before.

Comment: That's great, the box plot needs some love. Are your changes backward-compatible? The best thing to do would be to open a Pull Request on GitHub - that makes it easy to review the changes. Or if that's too much to learn right now, just open an issue with your example fiddle and an explanation of the proposed changes.

Comment: Yes, I have made it totally backward compatible, but currently introduced a new chart named BoxPlotJitter.  I can rename it to BoxPlot, because all the new attributes default to false and it will look just like the old BoxPlot, except for a fix to the yAxis.  This fixes the issue with boxes being squished for small values.  We are currently using dc.js 2.1.9 and Crossfilter 1.4.5

Comment: Sounds like we can just upgrade it with the same name, which is great. Let's continue the conversation on GitHub!

Comment: Great, I have continued the conversation with [Issue 1370](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1370) on GitHub for dc.js